# Why does C++ allow a member initialization type mismatch?

Tags: c++

I spent a couple of hours today chasing a bug, and although I found the root cause, I am puzzled that the compiler let it happen. Can someone better versed in C++ than me offer some reason? Or am I just expecting too much of the compiler?

I have a `TemperatureMonitor` class, which I initialise with a model, which it will use;

```
class PSTemperatureMonitor {
public:
    PSTemperatureMonitor(PSModel &);
    virtual ~PSTemperatureMonitor();
    void updateModel(char *t1, char *t2);
private:
    PSModel model;   // I accidentaly omitted the intended & here

};
```

I coded the constructor thusly;

```
PSTemperatureMonitor::PSTemperatureMonitor(PSModel &mdl) : model(mdl) {
    xTaskCreate( ds18b20Task, "TemperatureMonitorTask",TempMonTaskStack, this, TempMonTaskPriority, &hTempMonTask);
}
```

Surely the compiler should have complained that I was initialising a `PSModel` with a `PSModel` reference?

Comment: You can always create a copy from a reference - therefore the code is perfectly fine for a compiler

Comment: *Surely the compiler should have complained that I was initialising a PSModel with a PSModel reference?* Why?  It is a common idiom to pass by reference into the constructor so only one copy happens when initializing member variables.

Comment: *PSModel model;   // This should have been a reference  &model*... Ehr no then you should have used `PSModel& model;` for your member variable

Comment: OK, thanks - I guess I need more C++ experience :-)

Comment: @Greycon Yes C++ is full of things like this to learn. And reference members are tricky too. You really need to be sure your PSModel outlives the lifetime of your PSTemperatureMonitor. So designing well for ownership and lifetimes is very important in C++

Comment: Is your class supposed have a handle to the model or should the class own the model?

Comment: @NathanOliver That indeed is one of the ownership questions ;)

Comment: If PSModel should not be able to be copy-constructed, then the copy-constructor should be `PSModel(PSModel const&) = delete;` in the PSModel class.

Comment: Also worth noting that because a reference cannot be made to refer to another variable once initialized, reference members make it tricky-to-impossible to assign instances of the class.

Comment: Based on your question history, I'm guessing that there is some Java that you need to unlearn. In particular, a "reference" in Java is not the same as a "reference" in C++.

Comment: @molbdnilo Guilty as charged :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reference in C++ is not really a distinct type in the sense that e.g. `int`, `long`, `std::string`, etc. are distinct types. There is no operation that turns a reference into a non-reference or that makes a reference from a non-reference.

While a variable can have a reference type, an expression can not. If a variable of reference type is named in an expression, then it behaves *exactly* the same way as if the referenced object was named instead. The type of the expression is the referenced type, not the reference type. The point of a reference is to act *exactly* as another name for the referenced object.

So, whether you use

```
PSTemperatureMonitor::PSTemperatureMonitor(PSModel mdl) : model(mdl)
```

or

```
PSTemperatureMonitor::PSTemperatureMonitor(PSModel &mdl) : model(mdl)
```

there is no difference in `mdl` in `model(mdl)`. In both cases `mdl` is just a lvalue expression of type `PSModel`. The only difference is whether the expression's result refers to the parameter object of the constructor or whether it refers to the object that the reference in the parameter is bound to (i.e. the object passed as argument).

A lvalue expression of type `PSModel` can be used to initialize a reference to `PSModel` and, assuming `PSModel`'s copy constructor isn't deleted, can be used to copy to initialize a `PSModel` object as well. In the former case the reference is bound to the object that the expression's result refers to and the latter case the object is copy-constructed from the object that the expression's result refers to.

So, whether or not you use `&` in your member declaration, both choices are perfectly valid and have a useful meaning. Without the `&` you store a copy of the passed `PSModel` in the class. With `&` you store a reference to the passed `PSModel` object. The compiler can't know that you intended the other meaning.

Comment: I think it's frowned upon to post thanks, but thanks. Your explanation is clear, and of great help to me - I understand exactly what was happening now.